# Angularjs moving map with marker and get position current marker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I have a Google Map in Angular and mounted marker in this map. 
I want the marker to move along with the map. At the moment of the move, the marker is in the default position. How can I get the effect of moving the marker and get its current position.

My code:

```
<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-10 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-1" style="padding: 0">
                <div ng-if="!mapLoaded" map-lazy-load="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js" map-lazy-load-params="{{map.url}}" style="width: 100%;height:100%">
                    <div ng-map center="{{map.center.latitude}},{{map.center.longitude}}" zoom="{{map.zoom}}" styles="{{ map.styles}}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div ng-if="mapLoaded" class="map-dialog-container">
                    <div ng-map center="{{map.center.latitude}},{{map.center.longitude}}" zoom="{{map.zoom}}" styles="{{ map.styles}}">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is my controller:

```
$scope.map = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: {
                    latitude: 52.348763181988105,
                    longitude: 20.928955078125
                },
                url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXX&callback=initMap',

                NgMap.getMap().then(function (map)
            {
                var location = [52.348763181988105,20.928955078125];
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var markerIcon = {
            url: 'resource/img/mapin.png',
            size: new google.maps.Size(32, 41),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 41),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 41),
            labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(16, 55)
        };

                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location[0],location[1]);
                var newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                map     : map,
                icon    : markerIcon
            });
                        console.log(newMarker.map);
            });
```

Comment: Must the marker always be in the center of the map? Or will it be always in the same relative position as the beginning 'default' position?

Comment: Yes, the marker must always be in the center of the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a listener on the map's center_changed event. Set the marker's position to the map's center.

Add this to your js:

```
    map.addListener('center_changed', function() {

        newMarker.setPosition( map.getCenter() );

    });
```

For the marker position, you could do:

```
   console.log( newMarker.getPosition() );
```

Or more specifically:

```
   console.log( "Lat:" + newMarker.getPosition().lat() +
                "Lng:" + newMarker.getPosition().lng() );
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the marker remains in one position. The marker does not move along with the map

Comment: It should work. Could you create a jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: Try it now. I was using $scope.map, when I should've just used map.

Comment: I get error: $scope.map.addListener is not a function

Comment: ok, I should've used 'map' there - instead of '$scope.map'. See the edit.

Comment: Ok, It works :). Thanks. 
Can you still help me get the current position of the marker?
The marker moves with the map, but the position is not changed

Comment: Ok. I did it with get current position marker. Thanks for help dev8080 :)